# regex \\p{So} in not filtering BLACK CIRCLE FOR RECORD

Tags: java, regex

My question is about Unicode Character 'BLACK CIRCLE FOR RECORD' 
with is defined in Miscellaneous Technical block and Symbol, Other [So] category, [Ref](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23fa/index.htm)

This code is not working

```
String registered= "President⏺";   
System.out.println(registered.replaceAll("\\p{So}",""));
```

I get president⏺

With the BLACK CIRCLE FOR RECORD not being filtered by `\\p{So}` regex!

Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to find out exactly how Java interprets `So` class, but as of right now I'm going to call this one a bug.

Comment: @ctwheels If it was a bug in Java then why does it fails in php? I think there is a problem with regex101.com

Comment: @AniketSahrawat It matches in PCRE https://regex101.com/r/uEngJl/1

Comment: @ctwheels It is matching there, try running on a apache server. Same happens with Java compiler. So I think this is not a problem of php or Java. I strongly feel that the problem is with regex101.com itself.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat For PHP preg_* functions work you have to set `u` flag.

Comment: @revo Right, that's a problem.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat [it works in php](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLS6UoVcFWQV0/pqA6OL9Wv1TdmkuluKQIJBZQlFqcmZKaV/KofxdQmKugKDU9PjexJDkjPjEnRwOoU0cBpBZIgkVTi3UUAoJc3eODXUPi/YNcXIN0FAw0gRr19RUCijLzShRKMlIVgOZlAu0E61AA2lCaU8JVllgUn1KaW6ABMwio6/9/AA). Adding the `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` in Java doesn't present the same behaviour. This *should* be matching, but Java's implementation does not seem to be correct

Comment: @ctwheels Yeah, I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the code point of `⏺` which is `23FA` and listing all characters under `\p{So}` (`Other_Symbol`) category:

```
for (char ch = Character.MIN_VALUE; ch<Character.MAX_VALUE; ch++) {
    if (Character.OTHER_SYMBOL == Character.getType(ch)) {
        String s = String.format ("\\u%04x", (int)ch);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

We'll see:

```
...
\u23f0
\u23f1
\u23f2
\u23f3
\u2400
...
```

It's clear that code points `\u23f3` through `\u23ff` are not included however they should be according to [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt). You are able to match *BLACK CIRCLE FOR RECORD* which properly has fallen in `InMiscellaneous_Technical` block with `\p{InMiscellaneous_Technical}` in Java.

You are seeing a bug.

Comment: Fun stuff. `\p{InMiscellaneous_Technical}` works (just) in Java. `\p{So}` works in .NET, Ruby, Go, and both fail in languages like JavaScript, Python, Perl.

Comment: It's not *just* in Java. You can find more information on https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: Sure, this was *just* a report of my (non-exhaustive) findings with the particular code point at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote thie code to figure out the character unicode category name

```
Map<Byte, String> unicodeCategories = new HashMap<>();
unicodeCategories.put(Character.COMBINING_SPACING_MARK, "Mc");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.CONNECTOR_PUNCTUATION, "Pc");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.CONTROL, "Cc");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.CURRENCY_SYMBOL, "Sc");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.DASH_PUNCTUATION, "Pd");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER, "Nd");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.ENCLOSING_MARK, "Me");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.END_PUNCTUATION, "Pe");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.FINAL_QUOTE_PUNCTUATION, "Pf");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.FORMAT, "Cf");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.INITIAL_QUOTE_PUNCTUATION, "Pi");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.LETTER_NUMBER, "Nl");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.LINE_SEPARATOR, "Zl");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER, "Ll");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.MATH_SYMBOL, "Sm");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.MODIFIER_LETTER, "Lm");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.MODIFIER_SYMBOL, "Sk");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.NON_SPACING_MARK, "Mn");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.OTHER_LETTER, "Lo");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.OTHER_NUMBER, "No");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.OTHER_PUNCTUATION, "Po");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.OTHER_SYMBOL, "So");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR, "Zp");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.PRIVATE_USE, "Co");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.SPACE_SEPARATOR, "Zs");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.START_PUNCTUATION, "Ps");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.SURROGATE, "Cs");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.TITLECASE_LETTER, "Lt");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.UNASSIGNED, "Cn");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER, "Lu");

char registered = '⏺';
int code = (int) registered;
System.out.println("character's general category name = 
"+unicodeCategories.get( (byte) (Character.getType(code) ) ));
```

I get character's general category name = Cn

```
System.out.println(registered.replaceAll("\\p{Cn}",""));
```

I get empty string

So, the '⏺' is  in Character.UNASSIGNED category not Character.OTHER_SYMBOL category in java implementation !!

```
System.out.println("Unicode name of the specified character = 
"+Character.getName(code)); retun null because the code point is unassigned
```